# Notify observers when object attributes update

Tags: android, kotlin, observer-pattern

I have a `Singleton` manager class for managing request model and its attributes.

My main aim is update object observers when some of the object attributes changes.

```
class FlightSearchManager {

    private val _flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : MutableLiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> = MutableLiveData()
    val flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : LiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> get() = _flightSearchRequestModelLiveData

    var flightSearchRequestModel : FlightSearchRequestModel

    init {
        flightSearchRequestModel =
            FlightSearchRequestModel(
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null)
    }

    fun updateFlightSearchRequestModel(_arriveAirport : String? = null,
                                       _arriveAirportId: Int? = null,
                                       _departureAirport : String? = null,
                                       _departureAirportId: Int? = null,
                                       _departureDate : String? = null,
                                       _isRoundTrip : Boolean? = false,
                                       _paxTypeCount : List<PaxTypeCount>? = null,
                                       _returnDate : String? = null,
                                       _seatClass : String? = null) {
        flightSearchRequestModel.apply {
            arriveAirport = _arriveAirport ?: arriveAirport
            arriveAirportId = _arriveAirportId ?: arriveAirportId
            departureAirport = _departureAirport ?: departureAirport
            departureAirportId = _departureAirportId ?: departureAirportId
            departureDate = _departureDate ?: departureDate
            isRoundTrip = _isRoundTrip ?: isRoundTrip
            paxTypeCount = _paxTypeCount ?: paxTypeCount
            returnDate = _returnDate ?: returnDate
            seatClass = _seatClass ?: seatClass
            // Notify all listeners of live data
            _flightSearchRequestModelLiveData.value = this
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to notify observers I call:

```
flightSearchManager.updateFlightSearchRequestModel(_seatClass = "1")
```

This solution does not seem good solution. How can I write it more intelligently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you valuable feedback on your usecase, I would need more information, like: How do listeners listen? How does the caller look like?

How exactly does `_flightSearchRequestModelLiveData.value = this` notify all listeners of live data? Its not a function call, so how is an event created and pushed?!

Instead I will give some pattern advices you may need.

### Use constructor initialisation

1. Kotlin enables you to set fields over constructors. Even if your class is a singleton and all values are default - creating a constructor will enable to test your class easily (and other benefits).

So instead of:

```
class FlightSearchManager {

    private val _flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : MutableLiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> = MutableLiveData()
    val flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : LiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> get() = _flightSearchRequestModelLiveData

    var flightSearchRequestModel : FlightSearchRequestModel
```

try to go for:

```
class FlightSearchManager(
    val flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : MutableLiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> = MutableLiveData(),
    var flightSearchRequestModel : FlightSearchRequestModel = FlightSearchRequestModel()
) {
```

2. If you already have a constructor for a class and it is valid to have all fields to have default values - don't force the caller to set them!

This code is an anti-pattern:

```
flightSearchRequestModel =
            FlightSearchRequestModel(
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null)
```

What you should go for would be:

```
data class FlightSearchRequestModel(
   val propertyOne : String? = null, 
   val propertyTwo: Int? = null,
   ...
)

FlightSearchManager {
  val model = FlightSearchRequestModel()
}
```

### Parameters

It is seen as code smell, when your method has too many parameters, so I would recommend to reduce the number of those in `fun updateFlightSearchRequestModel`.

You could create a single function for every parameter change. Of course it means more lines to write, but is cleaner, straight forward and not as error-prone to side effects since you don't change ~20 things in one method.

### Naming convetions

I would guess that you coded with something like *C#* before, because of the usage of underscores `_` in variable names. Please try to follow the appropreate convetion for this language (Kotlin), as well as in Java:

> Local variables, instance variables, and class variables are also written in lowerCamelCase. Variable names should not start with underscore (_) or dollar sign ($) characters, even though both are allowed. This is in contrast to other coding conventions that state that underscores should be used to prefix all instance variables.

Constants:

> Constants should be written in uppercase characters separated by underscores. Constant names may also contain digits if appropriate, but not as the first character.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))

Fields like this:

```
private val _flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : MutableLiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> = MutableLiveData()
```

would become:

```
private val flightSearchRequestModelLiveData : MutableLiveData<FlightSearchRequestModel> = MutableLiveData()
```

---

Functions like this

```
fun updateFlightSearchRequestModel(_arriveAirport : String? = null,
                                   _arriveAirportId: Int? = null,
```

would become:

```
fun updateFlightSearchRequestModel(arriveAirport : String? = null,
                                   arriveAirportId: Int? = null,
```

### Immutability

Immutable code is easier to debug, to understand and to test. Favor `val` over `var` in (almost) every case.

If you really need to change something by reference, at least create a completely new immutable object. Example:

This

```
flightSearchRequestModel.apply {
            arriveAirport = _arriveAirport ?: arriveAirport
            arriveAirportId = _arriveAirportId ?: arriveAirportId
            ...
}
```

could become this:

```
flightSearchRequestModel = copy(arriveAirport = arriveAirport, arriveAirportId  = arriveAirportId, ...)
```